# Compile Latex table without \begin{document}?

Tags: tables

I have am creating a number of latex tables from another program and want to automatically view them after they are created.  They are automatically created without a \begin{document} but instead with \begin{table}.  Is there any way to compile the table files without imputing them into another latex document or editing the .tex file to include \begin{document} etc. ?

Ex. I would like to compile and view the following .tex file without having to edit it.   Is this possible?

```
\begin{table}[htbp]\centering
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\caption{Last Job Summary Statistics}
\begin{tabular}{l*{1}{ccccc}}
\hline\hline
                    &        Mean&          SD&         Min&         Max&Non-missing Obs\\
\hline
Held more than one job&        0.08&        0.28&           0&           1&        6010\\
Total hours from all jobs&       41.82&       12.55&           0&         150&        5089\\
Lost last job       &        0.78&        0.42&           0&           1&        6025\\
Quit last job       &        0.05&        0.21&           0&           1&        6025\\
Last job ended temporarily&        0.16&        0.36&           0&           1&        6025\\
Last job notice in weeks&        1.85&        5.60&           0&          97&        4959\\
Tenure (years) in last job&        4.65&        6.37&           0&          48&        5974\\
Received severance pay&        0.19&        0.39&           0&           1&        5959\\
Amount of severance pay&    26156.30&    75819.30&           1&     1000000&        1399\\
Expect to be recalled to last job&        0.14&        0.35&           0&           1&        5979\\
\hline\hline
\multicolumn{6}{l}{\footnotesize Estimates weighted using sample weights}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Are you using Windows, Linux or Mac?

Comment: why `*{1}{ccccc}` not `*{5}{c}` ?

Comment: Windows and the below answer works great.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the posted code is `tab1.tex` then a command line of

```
pdflatex '\documentclass{article}\begin{document}\input{tab1}\end{document}'
```

produces `article.pdf` that looks like:

[image]

(You might need different quote or to use `\\` for each `\` depending on your commandline shell, the above is bash)