# How to get the pdf of a compiled table only

Tags: tables, pdftex, compiling

I would like to generate a pdf document by compiling a table using pdflatex. For that I checked [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209225/compile-latex-table-without-begindocument) but the result there is a complete a4 page. is there a way to generate a pdf that has the size of the table.
For example let's assume we have the following table saved in `tab1.tex` from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209225/compile-latex-table-without-begindocument):

```
\begin{table}[htbp]\centering
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\caption{Last Job Summary Statistics}
\begin{tabular}{l*{1}{ccccc}}
\hline\hline
                    &        Mean&          SD&         Min&         Max&Non-missing Obs\\
\hline
Held more than one job&        0.08&        0.28&           0&           1&        6010\\
Total hours from all jobs&       41.82&       12.55&           0&         150&        5089\\
Lost last job       &        0.78&        0.42&           0&           1&        6025\\
Quit last job       &        0.05&        0.21&           0&           1&        6025\\
Last job ended temporarily&        0.16&        0.36&           0&           1&        6025\\
Last job notice in weeks&        1.85&        5.60&           0&          97&        4959\\
Tenure (years) in last job&        4.65&        6.37&           0&          48&        5974\\
Received severance pay&        0.19&        0.39&           0&           1&        5959\\
Amount of severance pay&    26156.30&    75819.30&           1&     1000000&        1399\\
Expect to be recalled to last job&        0.14&        0.35&           0&           1&        5979\\
\hline\hline
\multicolumn{6}{l}{\footnotesize Estimates weighted using sample weights}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

compiling this with:

```
pdflatex '\documentclass{article}\begin{document}\input{tab1}\end{document}'
```

produces:
[image]

what we would like to have is the trimmed **pdf file** containing  **only** the table that would look like:

[image]

Does anybody have an idea of how to generate the pdf of a table like above?

Comment: have a look at the `standalone` class :) and for your decimal columns, have a look at `siunitx`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One additional step, but might be of interest anyway:

Add `\pagestyle{empty}` to the preamble, so you have

```
pdflatex '\documentclass{article}\pagestyle{empty}\begin{document}\input{tab1}\end{document}'
```

and then run

```
pdfcrop article.pdf
```

where `article.pdf` is the file made by `pdflatex`. This produces a file `article-crop.pdf`. `pdfcrop` is a command line tool included in TeX Live and MikTeX. Without arguments it will crop away the outer whitespace from a PDF.

Answer (score 8):

try this

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}[2011/12/21]
```